# How to reference events on objects in a subform from inside the main form

Tags: vba, ms-access

Imagine a form that, for demontration purposes, contains only a subform and a textbox that need to mirror each other.

I tried to accomplish this by setting the **Control Source** on the textbox to the value of the field in the subform and this worked to make them mirror each other, but the textbox isn't editable so this is an unsuitable solution.

The next thing I decided to try was using the **AfterUpdate** event on both controls to run code that sets the value of the other control.

This is easy for the textbox:

```
'Set value of Notes field on subform whenever value of the corresponding textbox 
Private Sub Notes_Textbox_AfterUpdate()
    Me.subform.Form![Notes] = Me.Notes_Textbox.Text
End Sub
```

However, this isn't as simple for the subform field. I don't know how to reference an event on a field in a subform in a way that will still allow me to reference controls outside that subform.

As a demonstration, I need a way to do this:

```
Private Sub subform_Notes_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Notes_Textbox.Text = Me.subform.Form![Notes]
End Sub
```

I can access the subform fields AfterUpdate event within the scope of the subform but if I do that, then I can't access the Textbox because it is in the main form, not the subform.

So I either need a way to define an event function on a field in a subform from within the scope of the main form, or a way to make the textbox part of the subform while maintaining the subforms ability to open in datasheet view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure I get the whole problem (how does datasheet view come into play?), but this should do what you want:

(in the subform)

```
Private Sub Notes_AfterUpdate()
    Me.Parent!Notes_Textbox.Value = Me![Notes].Value
End Sub
```

---

Edit from comment: By far the easiest solution would be a continuous form instead of a datasheet in a subform.

You can have two textboxes, a one-liner in the Details section, and a large one in the form header or footer. Both have the same control source and are automatically updated when the other one is edited. No code required.

If it must be a subform-datasheet, you can use a similar approach: bind the main form to the same recordsource, and in `On Current` of the subform, move the main form to the same current record.

Comment: Ah, `.Parent` that's what I was looking for, thank you. Also, datasheet comes into play because I need that subform to load in datasheet view because that's how the client wants this form and I can't put a textbox into the subform without it either messing up datasheet view or the textbox not rendering fully like I need it to.

Comment: You are confusing me. Datasheet view implies that there are multiple records in the subform. What use is synchronizing a main form textbox with a whole column in the subform? Please clarify what you actually want to achieve. @MarkKramer

Comment: In datasheet view you can only see the first line of a string but the client wants all of the lines in this field to be visible when you select the record, which means I need to link a textbox to the field and the client wants the textbox to be editable which is why I couldn't just set the field as the textbox's datasource.